Trouble using Find Fit function
I'm trying to solve a parameter estimation problem in Mathematica using FindFit. I'm running into an issue where the solution involves complex numbers, which isn't what I'm looking for—I only need real-valued solutions. Below is the model I'm trying to fit, along with my current approach using FindFit.
Original Model
The model I have is:
μ = 1.209/2;
m = 1.209;

M[n_, l_] := 
  2 m + 3 a/γ + 6 c/γ^2 - 
   2 μ (3 a/γ^2 + b + 8 c/γ^2)^2/(
     2 n + 1 + Sqrt[(2 l + 1)^2 + 8 μ a/γ^2 + 24 μ c/γ^4])^2;

(* Data points to fit *) (* Each value in the brackets represents: {n, l, M[n, l]}, where 'n' and 'l' are input variables and 'M[n, l]' is the target value to fit *)
data = {
   {1, 0, 3.096},
   {2, 0, 3.686},
   {2, 1, 3.773},
   {3, 0, 4.040},
   {4, 0, 4.263},
   {2, 2, 4.159}
};

(* Attempt to use FindFit *)
fit = FindFit[
   data,
   M[n, l, a, b, c, γ],
   {a, b, c, γ},
   {n, l},
   Method -> {"LevenbergMarquardt"},
   AccuracyGoal -> 12,
   PrecisionGoal -> 12
];

fit

The Issue
The FindFit function is returning an error that looks like this:
FindFit::nrlnum: The function value {...} is not a list of real numbers with dimensions {6} at {a, b, c, γ} = {...}.

This seems to be because the arguments inside the square root become negative, leading to complex values. I tried adding some constraints, but FindFit does not directly allow inequality constraints.
What I've Tried So Far
I also tried using NMinimize to solve the problem, adding bounds and constraints to ensure that the arguments of all square roots are non-negative, but I haven't been able to reduce the fitting error sufficiently.
The expected parameter values are:

a = 5.9530 × 10⁻²
δ  = 0.27557
b = 0.5
c = 2.4277 × 10⁻²

However, I have not been able to achieve these values.
Does anyone have suggestions on how to get FindFit or another method to handle this properly and ensure I only get real-valued solutions? Alternatively, is there a better approach that would be well-suited to a non-linear model like this?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Why are you calling M[n, l, a, b, c, γ], instead of how you defined it M[n, l]? There may be other issues beyond that.

Attempting to fit a model having 5 parameters ($a$, $b$, $c$, $\gamma$, and $\sigma^2$ - the error variance) with just 6 data points is extreme wishful thinking.  I understand that more data points might be difficult to come by but with what you have, there is no hope of obtaining acceptable parameter estimates or useful predictions without lots more data.  A rule of thumb is that you need 20 data points plus 5 data points for every parameter.

Using the corrections in your code supplied by @UlrichNeumann gets you a result.  Looking at fit["CorrelationMatrix"] // MatrixForm shows that the correlations among the parameter estimators are all nearly +1 or -1 meaning that one can have no confidence in any of the parameter estimates. Yes, by constraining the parameters one can "replicate" the data points but that is by overfitting. If there is a theoretical reason for the model, there is not enough data or the model is much too complex for the amount of data available.

Change M[n,l] to  M[n, l, a, b, c, \[Gamma]] (see @Moo's helpful comment)  and try NonlinearModelFit with constrainted parameters:
    M[n_, l_, a_, b_, c_, \[Gamma]_] := 
  2 m + 3 a/\[Gamma] + 6 c/\[Gamma]^2 - 
   2 \[Mu] (3 a/\[Gamma]^2 + b + 8 c/\[Gamma]^2)^2/(2 n + 1 + 
        Sqrt[(2 l + 1)^2 + 8 \[Mu] a/\[Gamma]^2 + 
          24 \[Mu] c/\[Gamma]^4])^2;

fit = NonlinearModelFit[
  data, {M[n, l, a, b, c, \[Gamma]], a >= 0, b >= 0, 
   c >= 0, \[Gamma] >= 0}, {a, b, c, \[Gamma]}, {n, l}, 
  Method -> "NMinimize" ]

Show[ {Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Point[data]}], 
  Plot3D[fit[n, l], {n, 0, 4}, {l, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.2]]}]



@JimB Thanks, I am aware of that. My answer only shows how to proceed to get an approximation
